# Enchanté context

Tags: usage

The word *“enchanté”* is being said in a meaning "Nice to meet you", when you met new person first time.

Is it appropriate to say *“enchanté”* in a meaning "I am glad to see you again" to a person, that you already know?

Answer (score 6):

No, it would be like saying "nice to meet you" again. [to meet you] is always implied in *enchanté*.

If you want to express the pleasure of meeting *again*, it has to be explicit:

> Enchanté de te revoir *(sounds a bit weird)*

> Content de te revoir
>
> Un plaisir de te revoir *(better)*

Comment: Yes, *Enchanté* implies *de faire votre connaissance*.